# DAX efficient measure to get max date for max date and blanks for other dates

Tags: powerbi, dax

I would like to get the latest date of FactTable column in both ways (1) repeated all across table and (2) just in the max date.

The first:

```
DateMax Repeated Measure = CALCULATE(MAX(FactTable[Date]), ALLSELECTED('FactTable'))
```

The second:

```
DateMax Only Measure = 
VAR GetMaxDate = CALCULATE( MAX(FactTable[Date]), ALLSELECTED('FactTable'))
return
CALCULATE( MAX(FactTable[Date]), FILTER('Calendar', 'Calendar'[Date]=GetMaxDate))
```

The second measure (as desired) returns all blanks except the single date where date is max. Is there no efficient way then I did it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't need to use `CALCULATE` a second time. You should just be able to do something like

```
IF(MAX('Calendar'[Date]) = GetMaxDate, GetMaxDate, BLANK())
```

Comment: Yes. You'll still need to calculate what the max is.